# Program start testNG selenium tests freezes

Tags: java, selenium, testng

When programmatically starting selenium tests using testNG, the process freezes. All tests succeed, but the process does not end and does not return any exit code.

Example

Main.java

```
package com.example;

import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites = new ArrayList<>();

        XmlSuite xmlSuite = new XmlSuite();

        List<XmlTest> xmlTestList = new ArrayList<>();
        XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);

        List<XmlClass> xmlClassList = new ArrayList<>();
        xmlClassList.add(new XmlClass(TestOne.class));
        xmlTest.setXmlClasses(xmlClassList);
        xmlTestList.add(xmlTest);

        xmlSuite.setTests(xmlTestList);
        xmlSuites.add(xmlSuite);
        testNG.setXmlSuites(xmlSuites);
        testNG.run();
    }
}
```

TestOne.java

```
package com.example;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestOne {

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void prepare() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        this.webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        webDriver.get("http://google.com/");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void shutdown() {
        if (webDriver != null) {
            webDriver.close();
        }
    }
}
```

At startup

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 27439
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Apr 09, 2020 10:12:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

But the process does not end

Debug and Streis did not help much. Found out that AsyncHttpTimer hangs, which checks the port on localhost

Comment: Did you try WebDriver.quit() ?

Comment: @Sureshmani I tried - it did not help

Comment: Try this inside main: System.exit(0);

Comment: I suggest to create xml runner file instead of main function to run your tests. This way has some cons.

Comment: @NaelMarwan 

> System.exit(0) 

this solution works, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution to the problem. 

creating an xml file, unfortunately, is not suitable for my task with dynamic tests

Comment: This command terminates JVM, I'm not sure what you're trying to do and how do you intend to run your tests. Share us more info to help you out.

Comment: @NaelMarwan the list of actions for tests is specified in the json / yaml file, and then executed sequentially. For this, I used programmatic test generation.

Comment: Are you using CI tool? You run the tests in main and not in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the alpha version of selenium

there is issue on github https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8159

transition to 3 stable version solved the problem